# How should I scrape data from sublinks on a web using python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, url, beautifulsoup

I am a starter in web scraping using Python, so please forgive me if my question has very simple solutions. I need to scrape the name and location of all murals from this web: https://www.artworkscincinnati.org/public-art/murals/all-murals/ And below is my code so far. The problems are: 1. There are two duplicated sublinks for almost all murals. 2. I don't know how to extract information from the sublinks.

Can anyone please help me? Thank you!

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.artworkscincinnati.org/public-art/murals/all-murals/"
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

results = soup.find(id="main-content")
mural_elements = results.find_all("div", class_="details")

print("The total number of murals in Cincinnati and Northern KY is: " +str(len(mural_elements))) ## there are 169 murals in total as of 5/25/23

## scrape all sublinks from the main web
## how to extract one link only for each mural???
for mural_element in mural_elements:
  links = mural_element.find_all("a")
  print(links)
    for link in links:
      urls = link["href"]
      print(urls)
```

I tried the following code under the command of "for link in links:", but it didn't work and gave messy outputs...

```
## target sublinks
results_sub = soup.find(id="main-content")
      
#article = results_sub.find("<article>")
item = results_sub.find_all("div", class_="entry-item")
      
print(item)
     
## scrape info from sublinks
for element in item:
      
  name = element.find("h2", class_="entry-title")
  #content = element.find("h2", class_="entry-content")
  print(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Every mural has a thumbnail with `<a>` link, so you can extract the link from there:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.artworkscincinnati.org/public-art/murals/all-murals/"
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

links = [link['href'] for link in soup.select('.category-list-item .thumb a')]
print(*links, sep='\n')
print('Total:', len(links))
```

Prints:

```
...

https://www.artworkscincinnati.org/mural/the-roots-of-walnut-hills/
https://www.artworkscincinnati.org/mural/cheers-to-cincy-brewing-the-american-dream/
https://www.artworkscincinnati.org/mural/untitled/
https://www.artworkscincinnati.org/mural/st-vincent-de-paul-mural/
https://www.artworkscincinnati.org/mural/spring-festival/
Total: 169
```

Comment: Thank you Andrej for your quick response! Your answer definitely helped me fix the first problem. Do you mind providing some guidance about how to fix the second problem - extract the name and location of each mural from the links in the Prints?

Comment: @JessieH Just iterate over the links, and extract the required information from there. Shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Can you please direct me to some examples? I will also search online by myself at the same time, but in case I cannot find similar ones. I just started learning web scraping a few days ago and I still feel lost

Answer (score 0):

I found a very useful YouTube video [***Learn Web Scraping With Python: Full Project - HTML, Save to CSV, Pagination***](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GyB43hudfQw&list=PLRzwgpycm-Fio7EyivRKOBN4D3tfQ_rpu&index=29), and it helped me fix the problems in my question. The hard part was getting the location of each mural because this info was a div class next to a label with specific text. My final code is listed below:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import warnings
import csv


warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning) ## ignore the Deprecation warning message

s = HTMLSession()

## create a dictionary to assign index/key numbers to categories
Dict = {
    1: 'all-murals',
    2: 'murals',
    3: '2022',
    4: '2021',
    5: '2020-murals',
    6: '2019',
    7: '2018',
    8: '2017',
    9: '2016',
    10: '2015',
    11: '2014',
    12: '2013',
    13: '2012',
    14: '2011',
    15: '2010',
    16: '2009',
    17: '2008',
    18: '2007',
    19: 'avondale-murals',
    20: 'downtown-murals',
    21: 'over-the-rhine-murals',
    22: 'cincinnati-masters',
    23: 'cincinnati-neighborhood-murals',
    24: 'northern-kentucky-murals',
}

## define a function to get mural links from different categories
def get_mural_links(key):
    url = f'https://www.artworkscincinnati.org/public-art/murals/{key}'
    links = []
    r = s.get(url)
    details = r.html.find('div.content div.details')
    for item in details:
        links.append(item.find('a', first=True).attrs['href'])
    return links


## define a function to get interested info from a list of links
def parse_mural(url):

    r = s.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url), 'html.parser')
    name = r.html.find('h2.entry-title', first=True).text.strip()

    ## use try-except function because there are murals without location label
    try:
        location = soup.find('label', text='Location').find_next('div', class_='mural-spec-value').text ## most difficult part
    except:
        location = 'No Data'

    info = {
        'NAME': name,
        'LOCATION': location,
    }
    return info


## define a function to save the results to a csv file
def save_csv(results):
    keys = results[0].keys()

    with open('Murals_ArtWorksCincinnati.csv', 'w', newline='') as f: ## newline='' helps remove the blank rows in b/t each mural
        dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(f, keys)
        dict_writer.writeheader()
        dict_writer.writerows(results)


## define the main function for this file
def main():
    results = []
    urls = get_mural_links(Dict[1])
    for url in range(len(urls)):
        results.append(parse_mural(urls[url]))
        save_csv(results)


## won't run/import to other files
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```